# Your API key is invalid in React Native

Tags: react-native, access-token, checkout

I'm using `@wedoogift/react-native-checkout-payment` to integrate `cards payments` via `checkout.com`. Initialization is done successfully. When I tried to get **access token** by using following piece of code as written in the library description, I got the **error** `Your API key is invalid`.

**Initialization**

```
useEffect(() => {
    CheckoutModule.initialize('pk', 'sandbox')
      // or 'live' instead of 'sandbox' for production env.
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Initialization is done.');
      });
  }, []);
```

**Access Token**

```
CheckoutModule.generateToken({
    card: '4242424242424242',
    name: 'Card Owner',
    expiryMonth: '06',
    expiryYear: '25',
    cvv: '100'
}) // or 'live' for production env.
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('Card token is ' + result.id);
        // See CardTokenisationResponse in index.ts or index.d.ts 
        // to see the data structure of the result.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Failed because: ' + error.message);
    });
```

I don't know where to get it and where to place it. There is nothing in the library description about this API key.

How to resolve this thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key should go where `'pk'` (I guess this stands for public key) is in the example code.

For example if your API key is `0123456789`

```
CheckoutModule.initialize('0123456789', 'sandbox')
...
```

Comment: Yes its an public key but I don't where to get it.

Comment: You can get it from your account [here](https://api-reference.checkout.com/#section/Authentication/ApiPublicKey)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to mark it as a right answer so that upcoming person will get it helpful.